# Connecting a bluetooth speaker (Anker SoundCore 2) requests PIN

Tags: bluetooth-speaker

When I try to connect a pair of bluetooth speakers (Anker SoundCore 2) in Ubuntu 19.04, I get a popup saying I should enter a PIN on the speakers, but the speaker does not have a keyboard. How do I get past the PIN popup?

Answer (score 0):

The pin is not supposed to be entered on the speaker but from the computer. If your Bluetooth speaker has a default pin, just enter that and it should connect.

Comment: And it's typically 0000 or 1234 for such devices, if not printed on a label on the device.

Comment: The manual doesn't mention an PIN; the first popup says "confirm the bluetooth PIN"; whatever I input there (also tried 0000 and 1234), I get a popup that now says "Please enter (whatever pin I just entered) on SoundCore 2". I do hear a beal from the speaker after I confirm the first popup, but it remains in pairing mode.

Comment: Have you tried pairing with a smartphone? Does it require a pin?

Comment: When I pair with my phone I'm not asked for a PIN.

Comment: Try installing blueman. I find it better than default client. I use it with my Anker headphones and it doesn't ask for any pin.

Comment: I've tried with blueman, it sees the SoundCore, asks for a pin; whatever I enter there, I hear the "bing" from the speaker that it makes when it pairs, but it remains in pairing mode, and blueman says "failed to add device"